# ListBox in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, listbox

Someone knows how to create a ListBox in ASP.NET MVC 3 who will pass the selected checkboxs, for example, for the controller? I'm thankful for your help.

I have created this:

```
@Html.ListBox("selTipoVinculoTipoConvenio", new SelectList(Model.TIPO, "ID_TIPO_CONVENIO", "TXT_DESCRICAO"), new { @id = "selTipoVinculoTipoConvenio", @name = "selTipoVinculo", @class = "select-multiple w-464", multiple = "multiple", @data_width = "464" })
```

But now I need to create a filter with the selected checkboxs...

Just know a little bit about HTML Helpers of C# Razor.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Html.CheckBox` or `Html.CheckBoxFor` methods to create checkbox. However this method works only for a single variable, for multiple values (lists, arrays etc) you will have to use a loop, so it may be better to create editor template for your variable (`Html.EditorFor`)

Answer (score 0):

do it manually. Listbox helper just creates a  element for you.

create a select element and use the model to poupate it:

```
<select multiple="multiple">
   @foreach(var item in model){
       string checked="";
       if(model.checked){checked="checked='checked'"};

       <option value="@model.id" @checked>@model.name</option>
   }

</select>
```